# Example of a computation of the volume of a subvariety in projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, projective-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let us consider the projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$ with the standard Fubini Study metric.

I searched all over the internet but I can't find an example of a calculation of the volume for a projective subvariety $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ (we can assume it to be smooth of course).

For example given the projective plane $\mathbb{P}^2$ with coordinates $[x,y,z]$ and the smooth conic $$C:(xy-z^2=0) \subset \mathbb{P}^2$$ does somebody know how to compute the Volume $\textit{Vol}(C)$?
Or maybe a reference where a similar computation is carried out?
For simplicity we can assume that the ground field is $\mathbb{C}$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is nicely treated in §5.C of Mumford's *Algebraic geometry I: complex projective varieties* (Springer).

Comment: Thank you very much @abx

Comment: You are welcome.